# Create a Custom MessageDialog with scrolling

Tags: c#, windows-8, custom-controls, messagedialog

I have to show a popup in my Windows 8 C# app that displays a long list of information.

I want to do this in the same style as [MessageDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR208674), but MessageDialog does not allow scrolling so I need some form of custom MessageDialog, but am not sure how to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Callisto](http://callistotoolkit.com/) will help you with custom message dialog

[GitHub](http://github.com/timheuer/callisto)

[NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/Callisto)

[Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0526563b-7a48-4b17-a087-a35cea701052)